# Using a Sony ActiveX / OCX Control in a Windows Form - works in design time, not in debug/run

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer, ip-camera, sony

Visual Studio 2010 pro, .NET 4.0 w/ SP1.  Windows 7 64-bit OS, w/SP1.  x86 target application.  Sony SNC-RZ50n network camera.

Using a Sony ActiveX control, I am able to view the video feed from an attached (directly to my PC via crossover ethernet cable and 2nd NIC) network camera on a form containing the ActiveX control, but *only while in the design mode* of Visual Studio.  I activate the video feed by changing a parameter in the designer.  However, once I run/debug the application, the video feed no longer displays on the control (after changing that same parameter programatically).

The control is still present on the debug/run form, and I am verifying with WireShark that the video request is still being sent, and the video data is still being returned.  I can even use the Sony-provided "capture" button to display a still shot of the current video feed.  It's just the video box that does not display (in debug/run mode).

Any ideas why this might be happening?  I understand the design-time form I am seeing is not a true instantiation of my form, but of the base class.  The base is the same as this form, so there should be no gotchas there.

Here is a screenshot of design mode:  [image]
and run/debug mode, including what is seen after you click "capture":  [image]

I have put in a support request with Sony, but they are less than prompt in supporting this >6-year-old API.  This control is poorly documented, as you can imagine.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: 32-bit design time vs. 64-bit runtime? I am almost sure there is no support for this ActiveX. You would be better off forgetting the control exists at all, and using another maintained control or library that pulls video from this camera using one of the well known protocols.

Comment: @Roman, my debug/runtime target is specified to be x86. I actually tried changing the target to 64-bit and could not run the application, as the Sony library complained. So, I believe, and can verify on Monday, that everything in this project is x86 through and through.  
I would love to ditch this control as you suggested, however my application must utilize the MPEG4 stream output by the camera, which, you guessed it, is in a proprietary format. Neither Windows media player nor VLC can decipher this stream.

Comment: AFAI can see, this camera supports MPEG-4 over HTTP via `/mpeg4` HTTP request or via RTP. Both seems to be Sony specific, unfortunately, and it's only its M-JPEG `/mjpeg` is more or less compatible with those on other cameras.

Comment: I'd guess at incompatible window style flags.  Ensure that Opacity and TransparencyKey are default.  Take a closer look with Spy++.

Answer (score 0):

So until Sony decides to provide technical support for this issue, I have used a work-around of embedding their activeX viewer object in an html page, which I have then embedded in a form (via web browser panel) in my application.  I will update this post again if Sony ever gets back to me.